# Office.js outlook add-in issue

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to get the Body in Outlook and then update/set it with categories. My issue is this - when I debug it - it works fine. But when I don't debug from function to function - it gets all the way to the last function and just stops - updateBody(). What's really strang is if I remove the breakpoints on each function and just set a breakpoint on last function - never gets hit, but console will write out "Starting update body". All the console.logs are writing out data as expected. Not sure what is going on. Appreciate any help! Thanks.

```
"use strict";
var item;
var response;
var tags;
var updatedBody;

Office.initialize = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // The document is ready
        item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        debugger;
        getBodyType();

    });
}

function getBodyType() {
    item.body.getTypeAsync(
        function (resultBody) {
            if (resultBody.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                write(resultBody.error.message);
            } else {
                response = resultBody;
                console.log('Successfully got BodyType');
                console.log(response.value);
                getCategories();

            }
        });

}

function getCategories() {
    tags = "";
    // Successfully got the type of item body.
    // Set data of the appropriate type in body.
    item.categories.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        } else {
            var categories = asyncResult.value;
            console.log("Categories:");
            categories.forEach(function (item) {
                var tag = item.displayName;
                tags += '#' + tag.replace(/\s/g, "") + ' ';
            });
            console.log('Successfully got tags');
            console.log(tags);
            getBody();

        }
    });
}

function getBody() {
    var body = "";
    updatedBody = "";
    console.log("Starting get body");
    if (response.value == Office.MailboxEnums.BodyType.Html) {
        item.body.getAsync(
            Office.CoercionType.Html,
            { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
            function (result) {
                //Replace all the # tags and update again. 
                body = result.value.replaceAll(/#(\w)+/g, "").trimEnd();

                var domParser = new DOMParser();
                var parsedHtml = domParser.parseFromString(body, "text/html");

                $("body", parsedHtml).append("<div>" + tags + "</div>");
                var changedString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(parsedHtml);
                if (changedString != "") {
                    updatedBody = changedString;
                }
                console.log(updatedBody);
                updateBody();
            });
    }
}

function updateBody() {
    console.log("Starting update body");
    item.body.setAsync(
        updatedBody,
        { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html },
        function (result2) {
            console.log("Body updated");
        });
}
```

1. Image - With breakpoints on each function - works as expected
2. Image - Without breakpoints - gets to `updateBody()` function.
   But the string updatedBody isn't logged. It somehow skips over that
   even though it's called before `updateBody()` on `getBody()`
3. Image - Same code run via Script Lab - works just fine as well.

[image: With breakpoints on each function - works as expected]

[image: Without breakpoints - gets to updateBody() function. But the string updatedBody isn't logged. It somehow skips over that even though it's called before updateBody() on getBody().]
[image: Same code run via Script Lab - works just fine as well.]

Comment: To narrow down the issue, try to simplify all those chained functions and ensure that each one gets invoked in the previous callback. If that works, try to gradually add the remaining code till it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Sadly, I've tried that and also just doing the updateBody() call but still having issues :( - hence why I posted. I'm stuck. And it makes no sense that I can debug it with a breakpoint at the beginning of each function and it works, but if I remove the breakpoints - it stops working. 

And I can tell it gets to `updateBody()` as the console.log "Starting update body" is written out. 

Adding pictures to above to help better illustrate. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: FYI - I also loaded up Script Lab for Outlook and just tested it (love the program btw!)

It runs with no issues at all. I copied all my code and it ran and wrote all the stuff with no issues. So why does it work for Script Lab and debugger but not by itself?

Comment: Have you tried to create a ribbon button and run your code from the click event handler instead? Does it work in that case? The difference between the Script Lab add-in and yours is how the code is run - you put it inside the initialization routine while Script Lab's code is run by a button click at a later point of time.

Comment: I notice your screenshot is showing Outlook on the web. Another thing to check - does your addin work as expected with Outlook on Windows?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT - sadly no, doesn't work on Windows either. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - great idea! How do you trigger from the click instead of the manifest function call? I had a similar thought - but haven't seen any code examples for the ribbon button and want to make sure I'm not doing something unsupported. I was thinking I'd need to initiate the task pane like the Script Lab and have a button there with a run button click handler.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing a ExecuteFunction in your manifest?  If that's the case, you should have a FunctionName, instead of starting your method chain from initialize. Example:  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>your-method-in-functionfile</FunctionName>
                      </Action>

Comment: To clarify, are you running from ShowTaskpane or ExecuteFunction in your manifest. If ExecuteFunction, you should be starting your method chain from the FunctionName you specify, and not in OnInitialize.